# Spring security im getting 403 http code but everything seems OK

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, http-status-code-403

```
package com.kaan.securitydeneme.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user() {
        return "user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "admin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/mod")
    public String mod() {
        return "mod";
    }
    
}




package com.kaan.securitydeneme.config;

import com.kaan.securitydeneme.model.Role;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers(x -> x.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer -> authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer.requestMatchers("/user/admin").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getAuthority()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer -> authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer.requestMatchers("/user/mod").hasRole(Role.MOD.getAuthority()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer -> authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer.requestMatchers("/user/user").hasRole(Role.USER.getAuthority()))
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()); 

        return http.build();
    }

}





package com.kaan.securitydeneme.model;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ADMIN,
    USER,
    MOD;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
    
}





package com.kaan.securitydeneme.model;

import jakarta.persistence.CollectionTable;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Set;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean isEnabled;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> authorities;

}
```

```
2024-02-02T14:31:33.062+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user/user
2024-02-02T14:31:33.078+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-02-02T14:31:33.109+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/user/user?continue to session
2024-02-02T14:31:33.111+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-02-02T14:31:33.112+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@49cb8dbc
2024-02-02T14:31:36.637+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user/user
2024-02-02T14:31:37.194+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2024-02-02T14:31:37.207+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User(id=2, name=user, username=user, password=$2a$10$xgwLbHAS9SqY8E4EFqr5Nu7VSYhgwqOe3nEq9NkWsr0Gt0B58jvDO, accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, isEnabled=true, authorities=[USER]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=3005C8C63B903859A83A61919F7E77AE], Granted Authorities=[USER]]
2024-02-02T14:31:37.209+03:00 DEBUG 8465 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
```

When I reach the user with the correct role at all 3 endpoints, I get a 403 HTTP status code. What is the solution for this?

`

Comment: How are you doing your request, browser, postman, curl?

Comment: I tried browser and postman.

Comment: Its probably CORS but with not more info this is impossible to answer, good luck

Comment: sorry im new to spring security.
what exactly is the information you want?